# How to get nid of all nodes that are displayed inside a view?

Tags: views

I have view named 'xyz' set on example.com/xyz. I want to access nid of nodes that are shown by 'xyz' and show them on example.com/abc. I want to do it in a custom module. What hook i can use?

I tried to look into views API but no ups there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `views_get_view_result($name, $display_id = NULL)`

*API Docs:* [`views_get_views_result();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
Get the result for the current view:
<?php
  function views_get_current_view_result() {
    $view = views_get_current_view();
    return $view->result;
  }
?>
```

Heed that only the view items for the first page are returned. If the result array should contain all items then set the numbers of items per page to 0 (no limit).

**Structure of the result array**

The Array contains an object for each view item. Imagine a site has only one node then a node view type without fields and sort criteria would look like this:

```
<?php
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 1
        )
)
?>
```

[Refer this](http://drupal.org/node/342132) for more detail